# Рисование геометрических фигур в реальном размере на PHP?

Tags: php, графика, рисование

Существуют ли какие-либо библиотеки для работы с геометрическими фигурами средствами PHP дающие возможность рисования в реальных размерах (например в сантиметрах) и с возможностью масштабирования и сохранения рисунков для последующей печати в реальных размерах?

Comment: "Реальность размеров" это особенность формата, в котором вы храните фигуры. Либо он поддерживает реальные единицы измерения, либо нет. PHP тут толком ни при чём.

Comment: Тогда в каких форматах работать и каким образом взаимодействовать с ними средствами PHP?

Comment: В любых, которые поддерживают соответствующие единицы измерения. [В SVG они есть, к примеру (cm, mm, in).](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Introduction)